# Sending a list of strings from QML to C++

Tags: c++, list, qt, qml

I have ListModel which I manage in QML. After editing I want to send this model to C++ (as a QStringList for example, or something else I can work with in c++).

I know I can expose a list from C++ to qml and edit it from there, but for my app logic that does not really make sense. Can I somehow create a list like datatype in QML which I can send to c++ with a signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just send the `QStringList` to the C++ code and it ill be handled. See the docs linked below.

[`string QML Basic Type`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-string.html)

> When integrating with C++, note that any QString value passed into QML
>   from C++ is automatically converted into a string value, and
>   vice-versa.

[Data Type Conversion Between QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html)

> **Sequence Type to JavaScript Array**
>
> Certain C++ sequence types are supported transparently in QML as
>   JavaScript Array types.
>
> In particular, QML currently supports:
>
> ```
> QList<int>
> QList<qreal>
> QList<bool>
> QList<QString> and QStringList
> QList<QUrl>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason QVariants to send data (as I do), you can convert it the following way:

```
// Test if the value is of the correct type (not nessary of one is sure that it is a list of strings)
if (val.canConvert<QStringList>() && val.convert(QVariant::StringList)) 
{
    return val.toStringList();
}
```

Comment: …or just use a QStringList property? (not necessary to use QVariants). And what is the lone “val.toStringList()” about? it does nothing than to return a value, which is then not used.

Comment: How do i use qstringlist properly in qml and send it to c++? My answer is just the best i could find.